# How to implement a front end content filter using Orchard CMS? ie. a sort by Date/alpabetical drop down

Tags: orchardcms

Orchard provides filter options in the CMS where you can sort data by date, title etc on content.

While this is good I would like visiting users to be able to filter for themselves.

How can I implement a such a filter where users visiting the site will be able to sort content (ie Blog/news items) using a drop down box.

Many Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately the 'extending Orchard' tutorials have left me still wondering where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are QueryString tokens that you can use to filter a projection. All you have to do is build the form that will drive this.